# How to use this pan?

Tags: pan

Does anyone have any idea what this pan is called? It has a bottom dish and a rack that sits on top with several “legs”. It has a cover. There is a hole in the center of both the bottom part and the rack. I'm told it's from Argentina. I'm not sure how to use it and I can’t find anything online.

[image: pan photo]

Comment: I think, from the picture, the lid will sit on the upper tier, but is that right, or does it enclose the lower tray as well (in which case it might be useful for steaming)?

Answer (score 5):

It looks like a "smokeless" stove top grill very similar to the one my mother used to have. Unfortunately I can't find any pictures online but the setup is the same.

You put it on a burner and add water to the lower plate. Food goes on the perforated plate, and you put the cover on to prevent heat from escaping. Fat drips onto the bottom plate with water, so it doesn't burn and doesn't create smoke.

I don't believe it's a Korean grill plate; in those usually the center is closed, both for creating a hot spot and to prevent grease from falling on top of the burner. In the one from the question the food doesn't go directly on top of the burner, it cooks like in an oven not with direct heat.

Comment: That’s what I'm thinking, although I'm wondering if the water on the bottom is to catch drips rather than steam the food since it's open on the bottom.

Comment: @LizHonig you're right, I remember now; it was called a smokeless grill. I changed my answer to reflect that. I remember having food that was quite dry (from cooking for too long) so definitely not a steamer :)

Comment: It sounds rather like a way of cooking foods that wouldn't normally work on top of a stove, when that's all you've got. [Here's something similar on Amazon](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Non-Stick-Coated-Outdoor-Barbecue-Kitchen/dp/B073WHL3FF); that has a drip tray but also what looks like a more solid top than in the question

Comment: Another related item, without the drip tray or lid: [barbecue veg pan](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Neat-Ideas-Ultimate-Cook-much/dp/B01LD94DHW) (chestnut pans are similar).  I say related because in the same way you could grill things that wouldn't go on a wire rack

Comment: @ChrisH indeed, more like the one in your first comment. It's a marketing trick as it doesn't "grill" as much, since it's indirect heat - It won't _grill_ much without the lid

Comment: They all seem like a bit of a bodge to work around not having something proper, so it's not surprising there will be some variation in design, optimised for different foods.

Comment: Luciano, did the pan have a hole in the middle of the *lower* part, too?  Because that's the keeping me from thinking it's any of the things that people have mentioned so far

Comment: @Joe I do believe it had a hole, otherwise it would be boiling the water there _and then_ it would be a steamer for sure

Comment: looks more like a steamer, but other than that your description seems accurate

Answer (score -1):

This is stuff for the Korean BBQ grill. Pieces of meat that are prepped properly are grilled on this stuff. The fire is placed under the dish of the pan. Just look at this pic:
[image]

Comment: I'm not certain this is correct. Your image shows a largely- solid surface with openings around the outside only. The one in the question shows an even distribution of holes leaving very little surface area to brown the meat. Do you have another example that has a more similar perforation pattern?

Comment: Additionally, the pan in the original post is enamelled. That would never be the case for a Korean BBQ pan.

Comment: I've got a similar thing to this with a stone (granite IIRC) top, usable for Korean barbecue and similar techniques but also as a mini pizza stone (@sneftel).  It's hard to see how the perforated one in the question is similar

Comment: @Catija I had a similar one. It's not important if think my answer is wrong, just say it and I delete it.

Comment: Opinions on  the matter vary, but I think it can be better to keep a plausible but wrong answer.